# SQL Server use IIF calulated column by avoiding "Case expressions may only be nested to level 10"

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, case, iif

Below is the data I have

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPy5R.jpg)

The WH_QTY is the total qty available, VIP,A,B,C are the priority. for instance a product should be first allotted to VIP FIRST and then A,B,C.

By using case statements I have been able to get the correct values for VIP_Avail,A_Avail, but moving on to B_Avail I received the following error.
"Case expressions may only be nested to level 10"

All I am looking for is to use the VIP_Avail calculated column as a base for my A_Avail calculation and so on. But since I am Referring the entire case statements, its being off.

Below is the Query for VIP_Avail

```
IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH =0,0,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH>=ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH<ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH,0))) AS VIP_AVAIL
```

and below is the query for A_Avail

```
CASE
WHEN
ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH = 0 THEN 0


-- WHEN (WH_QTY-VIP)<A AND WH> 0 THEN (WH-VIP)
WHEN
((ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH-IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH =0,0,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH>=ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH<ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH,0))))<A AND ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH>0) THEN (ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH-IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH =0,0,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH>=ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH<ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH,0))))
-- WHEN (WH_QTY - VIP) >= A THEN A
WHEN
(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH-IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH =0,0,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH>=ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,IIF(ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH<ORDER_AVAILABLE.VIP,ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH,0))))>=ORDER_AVAILABLE.A THEN ORDER_AVAILABLE.A
END AS A_AVAIL
```

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: IIF is a different way of writing CASE...WHEN...ELSE END   Have you tried anything else, like making a scalar function returning bit, with program style IF ELSE logic within it?

Comment: I have tried IF else login but got the same results. I am a beginner

Comment: Can you explain your conditions with the words and not with the code? It's difficult to understand what you want, some conditions are repeated more times, for example ORDER_ITEMS.WH_OH = 0 is already mentioned as the first case, so why it's repeated further? It's already excluded because you used it as the first condition

Comment: If STK has 10 and VIP order is 5 VIP_Available should be 5, If A is 10 then A_Available should be 5 since 5 is already allotted to VIP. There are 3 to 4 conditions on the VIP Side which needs to be fulfilled and the same would apply over A_Available. As it is taking VIP_Available as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to update the table, I would do something like this:

```
UPDATE tickets_available
SET VIP_AVAIL = IIF(WH_OH > VIP, VIP, WH_OH),
    A_AVAIL = IIF(WH_OH - VIP > A, A , if (WH_OH - VIP >= 0, WH_OH - VIP, 0)),
    B_AVAIL = IIF(WH_OH - VIP - A > B, B, if (WH_OH - VIP - A >= 0, WH_OH - VIP - A, 0)),
    C_AVAIL = IIF(WH_OH - VIP - A - B > C, C, if (WH_OH - VIP - A - B >= 0, WH_OH - VIP - A - B, 0))

UPDATE tickets_available
SET VIP_AVAIL = CASE WHEN WH_OH > VIP THEN VIP ELSE WH_OH END,
    A_AVAIL = CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP > A THEN A ELSE 
        CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP >= 0 THEN WH_OH - VIP ELSE 0 END 
    END,
    B_AVAIL = CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP - A > B THEN B ELSE
        CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP - A >= 0 THEN  WH_OH - VIP - A ELSE 0 END 
    END,
    C_AVAIL = CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP - A - B > C THEN C ELSE
        CASE WHEN WH_OH - VIP - A - B >= 0 THEN WH_OH - VIP - A - B ELSE 0 END
    END
```

I used both IIF and CASE so you can pick the one you would like to use. Preferably you use IIF ofcourse, iit is far more readable.

Edit: Added select on request.

```
SELECT
    Item,
    WH_OH,
    VIP,
    IIF(WH_OH > VIP, VIP, WH_OH) AS VIP_AVAILABLE,
    A,
    IIF(WH_OH - VIP > A, A , if (WH_OH - VIP >= 0, WH_OH - VIP, 0)) AS A_AVAILABLE,
    B,
    IIF(WH_OH - VIP - A > B, B, if (WH_OH - VIP - A >= 0, WH_OH - VIP - A, 0)) AS B_AVAILABLE,
    C,
    IIF(WH_OH - VIP - A - B > C, C, if (WH_OH - VIP - A - B >= 0, WH_OH - VIP - A - B, 0)) AS C_AVAIL
FROM tickets_available
```

Comment: @cpatel13 Added a SELECT statement for your reference. Is this what you are looking for?